# Are there any non-concentration spells that consume a costly nonmagical component, besides True Seeing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

As per the title, limited to any official material published by WotC that isn't still in UA stages. I've scoured the wizard spells as best as I'm able and have only come up with True Seeing so far.

For context, the end goal here is a list of spells that could theoretically be cast with a consumable spell component that's provided by first casting a True Polymorph - if you try to start casting another spell with concentration (including any spell that takes longer than one action to cast) the True Polymorph will end and when you finish casting the spell the component no longer exists so the spell fails. I'm aware a plethora of them open if I involve another caster, but am assuming I'm the only caster at the table.

I've had the case situation of doing this to a creature with true seeing answered in another question, but am now wondering what other options True Polymorph might open up in terms of other spells that might have prohibitively expensive or rare nonmagical components, whether I polymorphed a creature or a rock.

Comment: I assume diamonds and gold dust that are consumed qualify for this question?

Comment: For diamonds, I'm okay with saying yes. I'm exhibiting caution towards anything in 'dust' form, however, as while I find it unlikely, the possibility exists to rule that a pile of grains of dust doesn't count as a single item, just like a bag of jewels would be multiple items (1 bag plus X gems).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Non-concentration spells with costly, consumed components and casting times less than 1 minute (no concentration):

- *arcane lock*
- *continual flame*
- *immovable object*
- *nondetection*
- *revivify*
- *divination*
- *greater restoration*
- *true seeing*
- *sequester*
- *time ravage*

---

#### Concentration spells with costly, consumed components:

- *tether essence*
- *invulnerability*
- *stoneskin*

---

#### Spells with costly, consumed components:

- *fortune's favor* (a white pearl worth at least 100 gp)
- *immovable object* (gold dust worth at least 25 gp)
- *tether essence* (a spool of platinum cord worth at least 250 gp)
- *time ravage* (an hourglass filled with diamond dust worth at least 5,000 gp)
- *create magen* (a vial of quicksilver worth 500 gp)
- *ceremony* (25 gp worth of powdered silver)
- *create homunculus* (clay, ash, and mandrake root, all of which the spell consumes, and a jewel-encrusted dagger worth at least 1,000 gp)
- *invulnerability* (a small piece of adamantine worth at least 500 gp)
- *mighty fortress* (a diamond worth at least 500 gp)
- *find familiar* (10 gp worth of charcoal, incense, and herbs)
- *illusory script* (a lead-based ink worth at least 10 gp)
- *arcane lock* (gold dust worth at least 25 gp)
- *continual flame* (ruby dust worth 50 gp)
- *magic mouth* (a small bit of honeycomb and jade dust worth at least 10 gp)
- *glyph of warding* (incense and powdered diamond worth at least 200 gp)
- *magic circle* (holy water or powdered silver and iron worth at least 100 gp)
- *nondetection* (a pinch of diamond dust worth 25 gp)
- *revivify* (diamonds worth 300 gp)
- *divination* (incense and a sacrificial offering appropriate to your religion, together worth at least 25 gp)
- *stoneskin* (diamond dust worth 100 gp)
- *awaken* (an agate worth at least 1,000 gp)
- *greater restoration* (diamond dust worth at least 100 gp)
- *hallow* (herbs, oils, and incense worth at least 1,000 gp)
- *legend lore* (incense worth at least 250 gp)
- *planar binding* (a jewel worth at least 1,000 gp)
- *raise dead* (a diamond worth at least 500 gp)
- *reincarnate* (rare oils and unguents worth at least 1,000 gp)
- *teleportation circle* (rare chalks and inks infused with precious gems worth 50 gp)
- *heroes' feast* (a gem-encrusted bowl worth at least 1,000 gp)
- *true seeing* (an ointment for the eyes that costs 25 gp)
- *resurrection* (a diamond worth at least 1,000 gp)
- *sequester* (a powder composed of diamond, emerald, ruby, and sapphire dust worth at least 5,000 gp)
- *simulacrum* (powdered ruby worth 1,500 gp)
- *symbol* (mercury, phosphorus, and powdered diamond and opal with a total value of at least 1,000 gp)
- *astral projection* (one jacinth worth at least 1,000 gp and one ornately carved bar of silver worth at least 100 gp)
- *true resurrection* (diamonds worth at least 25,000 gp)
- *clone* ? (a diamond worth at least 1,000 gp and at least 1 cubic inch of flesh of the creature that is to be cloned, which the spell consumes)